# Elements look offset, yet no offset is applied

Tags: html, css, web, web-testing

I'm starting to learn things like HTML, CSS, etc. And I've just made a new website to test out different things.

So far, I have navigation tabs at the top, and they work.

But the whole list just looks offset from the left side of the screen, even though there isn't any horizontal offset begin applied.

Here's a screenshot of what I'm talking about:
[image]

As you can see, the whole bar with the page links is offset from the left, and looks normal on the right.

Here's my CSS code that's used as the stylesheet:

```css
body {
    background-color: white;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 10;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #454b54;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: auto;
    border-radius: 0px;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}
```

I am completely clueless so far as to what could be causing this.

Comment: can you show your html code also ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, browsers will put a margin on the `body`.  Try adding this to your CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0;  /* Add margin: 0 */
    background-color: white;
}
```

Either that, or it could be the margin on your `ul`.  Try changing its CSS to:

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0; /* Instead of 10 */
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #454b54;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: auto;
    border-radius: 0px;
}
```

```css
body {
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #454b54;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: auto;
    border-radius: 0px;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">null</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">About</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">null</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, setting the body margin to 0 solved it.
P.S. The "10" margin is the vertical margin.

Comment: Awesome!  You may want to put the units then.  Example: `10px`.  And for vertical-only you will want: `margin: 10px 0;`:  vertical 10px, horizontal 0.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to add margin:0 to the body and html in CSS

```
html{
margin:0;
}

body{
margin:0;
}
```